# Python (2.7) - Simple IF THEN logic considering multiple fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, lambda

Attempting to perform something I can do in 5 second in Excel in Python and I'm finding myself very frustrated.

I have data that looks like this:

```
        HomeTeam AwayTeam  HomeScore  AwayScore  TotalScore
0        OAK      LAC         26         24          50
1        CHI      DET         20         13          33
2        CIN      BAL         13         49          62
3        CLE      BUF         19         16          35
4         NO      ATL          9         26          35
```

I want to create a NEW COLUMN in the data frame called "WINNER". If HomeScore > AwayScore, I want the new column WINNER to equal the HomeTeam value, ELSE, equal the AwayTeam value. For example,WINNER should = OAK on row 0 and CHI on row 1.

this is what I have attempted so far, but this did not give me the results needed above.

I know this is simple! Please help

```
#new df
df1 = df[['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','HomeScore','AwayScore','TotalScore']]

df1['winner'] = lambda x : df['HomeTeam'] if (df['HomeScore'] > df['AwayScore']) else df['AwayTeam']

print(df1.head())
```

Comment: look up pandas apply

Comment: thanks for the answering but looking up apply didnt get me very far. any other specific places I should look for examples like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that using numpy is an option you could do something like `df['winner'] = np.where(df['HomeScore'] > df['AwayScore'], df['HomeTeam'], df['AwayScore'])`

Comment: Much more helpful. Thanks for responding ... However I get an issue when I tried 

df1['winner'] = np.where(df1['HomeScore'] > df1['AwayScore'], df1.['HomeTeam'], df1.['AwayTeam'])



Its saying Invalid Syntax

Comment: Im dumb - This worked - Thank you - df1['winner'] = np.where(df1['HomeScore'] > df1['AwayScore'], df1['HomeTeam'], df1['AwayTeam'])

Comment: Is it working without the dots? `df` is a dict and the values are referenced via `df[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Try this:

```
df['winner'] = df.apply(lambda x :  \
                    x['HomeTeam'] if (x['HomeScore'] > x['AwayScore']) \
                                  else x['AwayTeam'], axis=1)
```

Comment: KeyError: ('HomeScore', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Are you sure you have a column called `HomeScore` in your `df`?

Comment: This works as well! Just another case of me being dumb ... My df was df1 instead of df ... THANK YOU